# Intelliji IDEA cannot run single test unless all tests are built successfully

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, blueprint-osgi

Using Intelliji Community Edition 2022.03 on windows 11, working with Maven 3.6.3 and Java-8.
Been experiencing strange issue: **I cannot run single Junit||Blueprint test if that test has problem, the IDE always try to build the whole test file and then failed at that single problematic test.** So the situation end up being I have to run all the test successfully in order to run single test. I am sure it is related to my local environment, because my colleges have no such problem we have everything the same. and I also have no such problem in linux VM.

[image]

**I have tried**

- install unintall different versions of IDE
- Modify test to not build before run, works, but if I change code, no auto detection, so barely

Any wise men got some ideas please ?

Comment: What do you mean that one test has a problem? Does it contain a compiler error? Does it simply fail an assertion? Obviously, all test classes are compiled to run tests. Hence, if you have a compiler error in one of them, none will compile and run. But if it's just a failed assertion, the rest should run without issues.

Comment: It seems your tests' code does not compile at all. If it were an assertion error, in the log it would not be displayed as error, rather as a failure. Failure means the test did not have expected result, error means it did. not even compile or it threw some exception in runtime

Comment: In maven the test compilation precedes the test run.  All source files must compile.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I think you are right, to explain more. a problematic test could mean a test that I was writing, or a good test that I change an argument on assertions to fail on purpose. The wired thing is my collegue has not such issue, and my Intelliji IDEA inside VM ubuntu has no such issue. Only my host machine, cannot run single test without run pass all tests.

Comment: You may try to run IDE with defaults ("File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings").